# Is there a Stack Exchange site for dealing with elderly parents?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I see https://parenting.stackexchange.com/, but there, I don't find many questions about assisted living, nursing homes, etc...  It is not a legal or a money question that I have.

My question regards an assisted living that said they could take care of someone to end of life. They listed one exception and that was if the resident was combative. My dad was non-weightbearing when accepted as a resident, but now they are saying it takes 3-4 people to help him to the bathroom, and they don't have the staff for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elderly) has an elderly tag, and there are assisted living questions there. Questions there do go as far as [advice](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/23588/7238) but on any site you are generally limited to one question; and perhaps some related ones. I don't want to go as far as suggesting that you have a question for our [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), but both sides would be expected to keep an agreement; and the facility ought to know what's involved in patient care.

You can ask your parents about their behaviour or better discuss with 3rd parties.

For a psychological perspective we have [Psychology and Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Our [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site is for parenting children, not addressing the needs of the elderly; though the help file there does mention that you can start a new site if our existing ones don't help that's hardly a solution to your immediate needs.

Comment: Parenting site purpose says: "Parenting Stack Exchange is for parents, grandparents, nannies and others who care for children."  Is there a way to ask them to include caring for elderly, perhaps as a new tags?

Comment: Neal, I think that counts as [a new direction](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1344/39406), but you *could* ask on their meta; I would expect to be turned down.

Comment: I don't know about IPS. OP's question is a conflict between a person and a company and IPS is about interactions with individuals. I would at least check with their Meta first.

Comment: @Rob those posts you linked aren't exactly *direct* examples of questions focusing on an interaction between a person and a company representative, they're examples of interactions taking place within the context of a work-environment. It would probably be more useful to link the OP to IPSs help/on-topic or the 'how to ask a good question' meta than linking them to a closed question, as that question is closed because it's not a good fit for the site. At least our help center includes that we do not a.) make arguments for you or b.) tell you who's right or wrong, both pitfalls OP should avoid.